# Outputting a LINQ query which has a join

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, linq, linq-to-sql

I am having problems getting a LINQ statement to output into a list in ASP.NET written on Visual Studio 2010. The function below attempts to search for the relevant DVD in it's data source and outputs one record:

```
 Public Function GetDVD(ByVal id As Integer) As DVDRaritiesDVDs _
    Implements IDVDDAO.GetDVD
    Dim DVD = From DVDList In _context.DVDRaritiesDVDs _
              Where DVDList.DVDID = id Select DVDList
    Return DVD.ToList().First()
End Function
```

But when I try to join it as so:

```
 Public Function GetDVD(ByVal id As Integer) As DVDRaritiesDVDs _
    Implements IDVDDAO.GetDVD
    Dim DVD = From DVDList In _context.DVDRaritiesDVDs _
              Join Category In _context.DVDRaritiesCategories _
              On Category.CategoryID Equals DVDList.CategoryID _
              Where DVDList.DVDID = id Select DVDList, Category
    Return DVD.ToList().First()
End Function
```

it gives me the following error when build the code:

> Error 1   Value of type ' (line 23)' cannot be converted to 'DVDRarities.Data.DVDRaritiesDVDs'.   C:\Users\a9010799\Projects\DVDRarities\DVDRarities.Data\DAO\DVDDAO.vb   24  16  DVDRarities.Data

Please can someone point out where I am going wrong so I can do it in one statement?

Answer (score 0):

In your query you return {DVDList, Category} against DVDList instance. 
You should use

```
Public Function GetDVD(ByVal id As Integer) As DVDRaritiesDVDs _
    Implements IDVDDAO.GetDVD
    Dim DVD = From DVDList In _context.DVDRaritiesDVDs _
              Join Category In _context.DVDRaritiesCategories _
              On Category.CategoryID Equals DVDList.CategoryID _
              Where DVDList.DVDID = id Select DVDList
    Return DVD.First()
End Function
```

or you should change signature of this method.

```
Public Function GetDVD(ByVal id As Integer) As Tuple(Of DVDRaritiesDVDs, DVDRaritiesCategories) _
        Implements IDVDDAO.GetDVD
        Dim DVD = From DVDList In _context.DVDRaritiesDVDs _
                  Join Category In _context.DVDRaritiesCategories _
                  On Category.CategoryID Equals DVDList.CategoryID _
                  Where DVDList.DVDID = id Select  New Tuple(Of DVDRaritiesDVDs, DVDRaritiesCategories)(DVDList, Category)
        Return DVD.First()
    End Function
```

Comment: I believe he intended to return a pair of two different entities.

Comment: then he need to change signature of method

Comment: Yes, that would be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns an DVDRaritiesDVDs object. Obviously your Linq query returns a list which contains pairs of (DVDRaritiesDVDs, DVDRaritiesCategories)

You should update your code in the following way:

```
 Public Class Pair
     Public First as DVDRaritiesDVDs
     Public Second as DVDRaritiesCategories
 End Class

 Public Function GetDVD(ByVal id As Integer) As DVDRaritiesDVDs _
    Implements IDVDDAO.GetDVD
    Dim DVD = (From DVDList In _context.DVDRaritiesDVDs _
              Join Category In _context.DVDRaritiesCategories _
              On Category.CategoryID Equals DVDList.CategoryID _
              Where DVDList.DVDID = id
              Select New Pair() With {First = DVDList, Second = Category})
    Return DVD.ToList().First()
End Function
```

Naturally you can generalize your code using generics, but I've decided to help you with the most simple to understand solution.